# Cloning pages using divi, Pages list not loading due to large number of pages

Tags: wordpress, clone, divi

I have to create a lot of pages using Divi and I created a template page and then started cloning it. Every time, i create a new page and click on choose page there I get list of pages available and I choose one of them (template page) and make changes in template.  It was working fine but now the total number of pages is more than 2200. and when I click on choose page it just stuck there and chrome says that page is unresponsive. I believe that it is because of a large number of pages so all of the pages could not list and it just hand there.
So my question is that is there any way to ignore all the pages except the template page. so that DIVI does not try to load all page for cloning. only the template page will be listed there and it won't take much time as 2200 pages do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly with "Choose page" you mean the options which popup after opening the Divi Builder for the first time on a page? => [Screenshot of Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyyB7.jpg)

If so you don't need to choose an existing page when you first created a template page and copied it. When you choose the copied page which was also created in Divi it shouldn't ask for loading a page. But if it does just try out the left option to start a new design. It should nevertheless show you created template page.

Comment: I resolved it but i was not talking about creating a new design, I wanted to clone a page but there were more than 4000 pages so all could not list in a feasible amount of time so it was taking so long to list all pages,